# jQuery doesn't trigger on iOS

Tags: jquery, ios

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(document).scrollTop() > 50)
            {

                $( "#hgr_top_navbar_container" ).addClass( "myClass" ); 

            }
        else{
                $( "#hgr_top_navbar_container" ).removeClass( "myClass" );
        }

    });
});
```

This is my css:

```
.myClass {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: rgb(255,255,255,1) !important;
}
```

My problem is that this code works on desktop, and it works on some Android devices. But it doesn't work on iOS devices at all? Is there any possible solution at all ?

Comment: You might wanna take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508995/does-jquery-work-on-the-iphone%c2%b4s-safari

Comment: @Jordy Thank you for your answer but I found my bug, I've used opacity on background-color: rgb(255,255,255,1) but forgot to add "a", it should be rgba(255,255,255,1).